# Fill in the gaps in the initials function so that it returns the initials of the words contained in the phrase received, in upper case

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

#original code

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.___
    result = ""
    for word in words:
            result += ___
    return ___
    
print(initials("Universal Serial Bus")) # Should be: USB
print(initials("local area network")) # Should be: LAN
    
print(initials("Operating system")) # Should be: OS
```

Comment: Add your current approach

Comment: Sorry, but no. You go first. Please update your question with the code you have tried and any problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Please next time put some of your code that you are struggling with and problems you encountered.

```
def initials(phrase):
    return ''.join(word[0].upper() for word in phrase.split())


print(initials('Universal Serial Bus'))
print(initials('local area network'))
print(initials('Operating system'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def initials(phrase):
    words = phrase.split()                #splits given data into list  
    result = ""
    for word in words:                    #iterates word in 'words'
        result += word[0].upper()         #stores 1st letter in Uppercase
    return result

print(initials("Universal Serial Bus")) # Should be: USB
print(initials("local area network")) # Should be: LAN
print(initials("Operating system")) # Should be: OS
```